# How to create multi-series line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am writing to seek help, in how do can I create multi-series line chart from [name] column below.  Currently, I am plotting the chart using [date] and [tag] points. However, I would like to show multi-series line chart for each names.  Is this plausible or does this task require manual functions to be created to link in with the API.

Please advice.

```
 function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Tag', 'Date'],
          ['ACCA', 45, 'May 14'],
          ['ABBA', 85, 'May 14'],
          ['ANNA', 100, 'May 14'],
          ['AMMA', 100.5, 'May 14'],
          ['ACCA', 99.5, 'May 15'],
          ['ABBA', 85.5, 'May 15'],
          ['ACCA', 99.6, 'May 15'],
          ['BACM', 94, 'May 15'],
          ['MMBS', 96, 'May 15']
        ]);

        // Define category pickers for 'Name',
        var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'control1',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
                'ui': {
                    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                    'allowTyping': false,
                    'allowMultiple': false
                }
            }
        });

        var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'LineChart',
            'containerId': 'chart1',
            'options': {
                'width': 400,
                'height': 300,
                'chartArea': { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }
            },
            // Configure the Linechart to use columns 2 (Date) and 1 (Tag)
            'view': { 'columns': [2, 1] }
        });

        // Define a table.
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Table',
            'containerId': 'chart2',
            'options': {
                'width': '300px'
            }
        });

        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind([countryPicker], [barChart, table]).draw(data);
        }
```

***Edit:***

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want each name to be a data series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, I would suggest removing the LineChart from your Dashboard, and using the Table's "ready" event to get the filtered data, create appropriate settings for the chart's `view.columns` parameter, and then drawing the chart with the filtered data:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    var filteredData = table.getDataTable();
    // get a list of all the labels in column 0
    var group = filteredData.getDistinctValues(0);

    // build the columns for the view
    var columns = [0];
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        var label = group[i];
        // set the columns to use in the chart's view
        // calculated columns put data belonging to each country in the proper column
        columns.push({
            type: 'number',
            label: label,
            calc: (function (name) {
                return function (dt, row) {
                    return (dt.getValue(row, 0) == name) ? dt.getValue(row, 1) : null;
                }
            })(label)
        });
    }
    var view = barChart.getView() || {};
    view.columns = columns;
    barChart.setView(view);
    barChart.setDataTable(filteredData);
    barChart.draw();
});
new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind([countryPicker], [table]).draw(data);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response and solution.  the multi-series is showing on the graph through scatter plots.  would i need to create separate function, which can group the same 'names', to plot together[i.e. ACCA], as a multi-line series.  Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: To make them appear as lines, you need to pick out a column to use for the x-axis values that is different from the name column.  Set it on this line: `var columns = [0];`.

Comment: Hi,I have tried changing the x-axis value to [2], but I am still seeing the scatter plots for the names.  I have uploaded the latest code on jsfiddler- http://jsfiddle.net/mis786/FRz59/7/. Please advice, if possible. Many thanks.